# how with phonegap to retrieve data from remote php/mysql server

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I am trying to build ios app using phonegap

I want that data from my remote server display in phonegap. 
On my server i have php/mysql, on client side i have phonegap and developing app in jquery mobile.

I know that i need to use jsonp but i have problem.

On server side i developed very simple app.

I have **two php pages**.

**First php page - list.php**, display list of navigation (home, about us, gallery). 
**Second php page - text.php** display info about list.php. For example for about page it display "about us" information, for gallery it display images and some text information...

On client side i also have two html pages.

**list.html** - that page i successfuly connect with list.php using jsonp.

On list.html - i pull data from my remote server and display navigation (home, about us, gallery). So that page display navigation list, nothing special.

**listtext.html** - this is problematic html page, which i don't know how to solve.

When user open list.html in browser, he can click on home button or on about us button (i make link in good format: listtext.html?id=1) **but i don't know how to parse on listtext.html**. I suppose that i need to have get, but i don't know how to do.

So on listtext.html i need to see detailed information for home, about us, gallery.

I attached code - this is **listtext.html** page - just javascript because problem is sure here

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var output = $('.nesa');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/text.php',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

                 var final= item.id;


                output.append(final);
             });
         },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });

 });
```

this is **text.php** page:

```
    <?php

//header('Content-type: application/json');
```

include 'config.php';

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$id=$_GET['id']; // Collecting data from query string

$sql = "select * from ios where id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$records[] = $row;

}

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';

```
?>
```

I am sure that text.php is ok, i encoded in jason. I got jsonp output from text.php
When i click mysite.com/text.php?id=1 i got info for "home" page in jason format.

But my problem is in javascript (jquery), because i don't know how to parse.

So could you help me how to parse with jason in javascript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
success: function(data, status){
   var jsonData = JSON.parse( data );
}
```

And you can use jsonData
For examnple to get length `jsonData.length`

Comment: Hello, i didn't succeed. I am working with jquery. Can anyone help me i am really stuck. Thanks

Comment: Can you paste a JSON response?

Comment: I don't get any response. I am watching in firefox in console, there are no errors. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can see all your requests on server and responses in FF, if you right click on page go to Inspect Element, and open Network tab, and you will see your requests, if you click on some request you will see on right side response tab, click on it and there will be your response. If you don't get anything then something is wrong with your php or maybe you are sending some wrong parametars. [View image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9ckfwa2nisqp34/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-01%20at%2009.06.17%20%282%29.png)

Comment: Hello friends, i have still no solution. From request from server i got Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. But i got that error because i don't know how to write proper .ajax syntax. I need in javascript somehow to pass get from php. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Ok. Check out some examples on [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) Or if you are using jquery: [Jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [Jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or [Jquery get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)